# Regular expression assistance

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a client's site that keeps getting hacked with XSS injections somehow. These XSS attacks are without fail in the banners section, and the banner ads need to have `<script>` tags to function.

I am still trying to figure out where and when this happens (it is a HUGE site, is badly coded (sorry, previous guy...) and I am really swamped. So, in the mean time, I want to do a regular expression that deletes the partial  tag that gets inserted.

So, if the script should be:

```
<script src="valid_script.js"></script>
```

The hacker simply does this:

```
<script src="valid_script.js"></script>
<script src="invalid_script.js"></script>
```

I need the regex to delete the script tag (there may be multiple matches) that contains "invalid_script.js" but leave the one that contains "valid_script.js" in tact.

**My question:** Could you experts out there please show me how to do this regex? I am sorry, but I do not understand regex, I tried so hard to understand, but it is way over my head :-(

Comment: Sounds kind of a suicide squad to me; trying to get rid of hacking attacks with a technology (Regex) you claim to not understand.

Comment: you cant fix it on the client, it needs to be fixed on the server.You need to escape your HTML on the server.

Comment: Fix the security leak, it's the **only** reasonable way.

Comment: Are you using some 3rd-party banner ad service via <script> tags?

Comment: @UweKeim: Well, I know at least part of what regex does - pattern matching - which is what I want to do here, but I can't write it. I know the hole has to be fixed, and I am working towards that, but in the mean time, I need to have a way to at least keep the site running as best I can until a better solution is found.

Comment: @mpm: yes, it has to be fixed, but for now I need to keep things running as best as I can until we can fix the security for good. How do other people deal with this kind of problem? I am sure I am not the first person who has to deal with this? Hence I asked the question. I did not ask for confirmation that the system is messy, broken or whether I am attempting suicide by regex. I was thinking of using this regex to filter out bad items as they occur, until such time that I can get a proper fix, and also hoping someone here has an idea on how I could implement such a proper fix ;-) Thanks!

Comment: @IngoBürk: Yes, agreed. But I need a short term relief. Any thoughts?

Comment: you cant fix that with a regexp on the client,period.How would it work? It cannot , everything is client side, it's too late to filter out the page.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh Typically, you want to roll back your site to a safe version, deactivate the page with the leak, deactivate the feature with the leak or, if it comes down to it, take down the entire site. Yes, even somewhat big sites do that when being attacked. User security is your responsibility and is more important than uptime. Big sites usually don't have to go offline entirely because they a) are well-programmed, b) can solve problems quickly through experts and c) are built modular to take out individual parts that are affected.

Comment: @IngoBürk thank you. While I do concede that this hacking could've happened if I have built the site, I would've been more comfortable. There is no roll-back opportunity - there are no backups. I am stuck in a dreadful situation, and just trying to make it work, somehow.

Comment: @mpm: The data is saved to the database when it is uploaded, when the ads get pulled, a PHP script retrieves from the database. The PHP processes the code BEFORE it is sent to the browser, so this can be done, providing you maintain a list of scripts to exclude. So - will it buy me time *IF* I can get a regex to work *AND* we maintain the list of hacks as we discover them? That is what I want to know. I have a feeling 'Yes, it would', but wanted to make sure. Would it solve my problem? 'No, I know it won't, but I need time to try and fix it for good'. I hope I make more sense now...?

Comment: your question doesnt mention php anywhere.If you want help,be accurate.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh Just some general thoughts: Users will be more understanding of a downtime than being attacked through your site. If isolated parts can't be taken down, taking the entire site offline must be considered (even bigger sites like ubuntuforums.org had to do it before). Using workarounds is always a bad idea, but especially so when it comes to security. *Someone* obviously is targetting you. In any case, when this is over, take it as an argument to get some budget to improve the quality.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thank you - very valuable insights. I asked the client if we could take the site offline, and they said they'd prefer not to, as it is three single ladies running it, and it is their only income. Their budget does not allow for redeveloping the site in a short time-frame, so I am tasked to try and keep the site running as effectively and cheaply as possible. I know that I probably should've insisted more, because all the comments here indicate that I did not follow the right way of doing things, and I thank all for helping, but I am in this situation now, and am trying to make do.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh I understand that you can only do so much and I think as a developer you have done your duty of informing the business owners. Ultimatively, it's up to them just as it will be their responsibility if they lose customers (or even worse, get sued) because of this. A developer can only try to make them understand the technical point of view and advice. I wish you best of luck that you can close this security leak soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking note of all the comments, as you have, to answer your question if you have the text to be outputted in the `$content` variable (that will be containing both the good and the bad script), then the following regular expression will strip just the bad:

```
$content = preg_replace('#<script[^>]*invalid_script\.js[^>]*></script>#s', '', $content);
```

This says, briefly, look for the following in sequence: `<script`, a string of non-`>` characters, `invalid_script.js`, a string of non-`>` characters, and `></script>`.

But to reiterate all the comments, this could be got around and is certainly only a sticking plaster of sorts.

Comment: Hi Matthew,Thank you very much. I know the root cause has to be fixed. I just need a solution that can keep the site running while I am working through all the code. One question that came up that did not get answered yet, is how people deal with such things in general? Where you need to have <script> tags, but have to keep some out and some not? With reputable sources this should not be the case, and the client use reputable ad sources, so, I need to find out where they come in, but what if an ad provider is providing this code to an administrator of the site? Is there a way to sort this out?

Comment: If your ad banner is output within an iframe, you could use iframe's sandbox attribute to lock it down a bit, but I don't think that would help with your situation of good+bad script: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/ . If you really can't have a situation where you don't allow arbitrary HTML from a third party, then you should at the least operate a whilelist system where only the element you know is safe is allowed or similar.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I will switch from a blacklist approach to a whitelist approach. It will mean less maintenance. I believe your regex will still work as is. (If not in whitelist, then do not display) as opposed to (if in blacklist, then do not display). Thanks for your help!